# Regular expression to match only spaces in between the words

Tags: regex, regex-group

```
  'Store Domain'                     => '',
  'Store Country'                    => '',
  'Store Phone Reveals Last 7 Days'  => '',
  'Store Phone Reveals Last 30 Days' => '',
```

Regex noob here, I have the above text, I need to match the spaces inbetween the words. 
eg `'Store_Domain'`.

I have tried `(\w+\s?)` expression, but it matches the word also,

How do I specify that

- it starts with **'** (quote)
- then a word and space (this group can be present multiple time) **and I need to match only space in this group**
- then it ends with another **'**(quote)

**Edit:**

Hmm... The flagged answer didn't help me though. Here is a link to regexr. https://regexr.com/3vqf8

Comment: You can use this one to solve your problem.. `$text = preg_replace('~(?:\G(?!\A)|')[^'\s]*\K(?:\s|'(*SKIP)(*F))~', '#', $text); `